# A quickie: python, terminal "print command not found"

Tags: python, macos, terminal, bbedit, textwrangler

Been using terminal to run python scripts written in textwrangler for about 18 months. Decided to look at possibility of moving to an IDE so downloaded a couple of trial versions. Just downloaded BBEedit and suddenly having problems executing script, either from BBedit or Textwrangler. The following code:

```
print "Please work"

for i in range(50):
    print i
```

yields the following error message:

```
/Users/paulpatterson/Documents/Python/Scripts/t.py: line 1: print: command not found
/Users/paulpatterson/Documents/Python/Scripts/t.py: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/Users/paulpatterson/Documents/Python/Scripts/t.py: line 3: `for i in range(50):'
```

Some files still work okay, but I'm struggling to figure out why others now aren't - 
not even sure if BBedit download has caused the problem.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try putting

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

at the top of the script. The program is trying to execute it like a shell script instead of running it through python.

Comment: No worries, Paul. We all learn this by being bitten by it a few times. :)

Answer (score 1):

It's running the script as a shell script, not a Python script.

Answer (score 0):

Also, be aware that this form of print (print-as-command) is changing to print-as-a-function when you convert to Python 3.  So:

```
print "please work"
```

will have to be changed to:

```
print ("please work")
```